# 2D Array from exec output

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have the code

```
foreach ($retval as $line) {  // process array line by line
    echo "$line \n";
}
```

and it gives me a nice array with output of

```
FieldType: Text 
FieldName: Job title 
FieldFlags: 0 
FieldValue: ICT Manager 
FieldJustification: Left
--- 
FieldType: Text 
FieldName: Hours Per Week 
FieldFlags: 0 
FieldValue: 35 
FieldJustification: Left 
--- 
FieldType: Text 
FieldName: Reporting To 
FieldFlags: 0 
FieldValue: Jerry Woolner 
FieldJustification: Left 
--- 
FieldType: Text 
FieldName: Main Duties/Repsonsibilities 
FieldFlags: 4096 
FieldValue: dfhg fdhg fgh fghfgh fgh dfghdfghfdgh dfgh dfghfdgh gfhdfgh h fgh dfghdfghfdgh dfgh dfghfdgh gfhdfgh h fgh dfghdfghfdgh dfgh dfghfdgh gfhdfgh h fgh dfghdfghfdgh dfgh dfghfdgh gfhdfgh h fgh dfghdfghfdgh dfgh dfghfdgh gfhdfgh h fgh dfghdfghfdgh dfgh dfghfdgh gfhdfgh h fgh dfghdfghfdgh dfgh dfghfdgh gfhdfgh h fgh dfghdfghfdgh dfgh dfghfdgh gfhdfgh h fgh dfghdfghfdgh dfgh dfghfdgh gfhdfgh h fgh dfghdfghfdgh dfgh dfghfdgh gfhdfgh h fgh dfghdfghfdgh dfgh dfghfdgh gfhdfgh h fgh dfghdfghfdgh dfgh dfghfdgh gfhdfgh h fgh dfghdfghfdgh dfgh dfghfdgh gfhdfgh h fgh dfghdfghfdgh dfgh dfghfdgh gfhdfgh h fgh dfghdfghfdgh dfgh dfghfdgh gfhdfgh h fgh dfghdfghfdgh dfgh dfghfdgh gfhdfgh 
FieldJustification: Left
```

I now want to get this as a 2D array so that the output will be what i need which is

```
Array [0]
      array[0] = FieldType: Text 
      array[1] = FieldName: Job title 
      array[2] = FieldFlags: 0 
      array[3] = FieldValue: ICT Manager 
      array[4] = FieldJustification: Left 
      array[5] = --- 

Array [1]
      array[0] = FieldType: Text 
      array[1] = FieldName: Hours Per Week 
      array[2] = FieldFlags: 0 
      array[3] = FieldValue: 35 
      array[4] = FieldJustification: Left 
      array[5] = --- 

etc etc
```

how can i do this ?

current output vardump is

```
array(25) { [0]=> array(0) { } [1]=> string(3) "---" [2]=> string(15) "FieldType: Text" [3]=> string(20) "FieldName: Job title" [4]=> string(13) "FieldFlags: 0" [5]=> string(23) "FieldValue: ICT Manager" [6]=> string(24) "FieldJustification: Left" [7]=> string(3) "---" [8]=> string(15) "FieldType: Text" [9]=> string(25) "FieldName: Hours Per Week" [10]=> string(13) "FieldFlags: 0" [11]=> string(14) "FieldValue: 35" [12]=> string(24) "FieldJustification: Left" [13]=> string(3) "---" [14]=> string(15) "FieldType: Text" [15]=> string(23) "FieldName: Reporting To" [16]=> string(13) "FieldFlags: 0" [17]=> string(25) "FieldValue: Jerry Woolner" [18]=> string(24) "FieldJustification: Left" [19]=> string(3) "---" [20]=> string(15) "FieldType: Text" [21]=> string(39) "FieldName: Main Duties/Repsonsibilities" [22]=> string(16) "FieldFlags: 4096" [23]=> string(686) "FieldValue: dfhg fdhg fgh fghfgh fgh dfghdfghfdgh dfgh dfghfdgh gfhdfgh h fgh dfghdfghfdgh dfgh dfghfdgh gfhdfgh h fgh dfghdfghfdgh dfgh dfghfdgh gfhdfgh h fgh dfghdfghfdgh dfgh dfghfdgh gfhdfgh h fgh dfghdfghfdgh dfgh dfghfdgh gfhdfgh h fgh dfghdfghfdgh dfgh dfghfdgh gfhdfgh h fgh dfghdfghfdgh dfgh dfghfdgh gfhdfgh h fgh dfghdfghfdgh dfgh dfghfdgh gfhdfgh h fgh dfghdfghfdgh dfgh dfghfdgh gfhdfgh h fgh dfghdfghfdgh dfgh dfghfdgh gfhdfgh h fgh dfghdfghfdgh dfgh dfghfdgh gfhdfgh h fgh dfghdfghfdgh dfgh dfghfdgh gfhdfgh h fgh dfghdfghfdgh dfgh dfghfdgh gfhdfgh h fgh dfghdfghfdgh dfgh dfghfdgh gfhdfgh h fgh dfghdfghfdgh dfgh dfghfdgh gfhdfgh h fgh dfghdfghfdgh dfgh dfghfdgh gfhdfgh" [24]=> string(24) "FieldJustification: Left" }
```

Comment: What is the current output of: `var_dump($retval);` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

Just [`array_chunk()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) your array into chunks of 6 an done:

```
$chunked = array_chunk($retval, 6);
print_r($chunked);
```

Comment: Thats great and pretty much works but sometimes it may have more than 6 fields. ideally i need it to chunk it by the --- field

Comment: @Lee Then use [`array_search()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) to search for `---` take the `(key+1)` and then you have your chunk size